# Parse JSON in Jquery with an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to cancel all my listings on Bitskins, but they have a weird system where each listing is unique, even if its for the same item. Meaning my 88 pages of listings is an absolute pain to remove.

So I thought of going the autohotkey route, but my end goal is to actually use the API to create specific listings. So I wrote a little test script/link.

```
https://bitskins.com/api/v1/cancel_buy_order/?api_key=myapikey&code=mycode&buy_order_id=995544
```

It worked. I proceeded to make a html with a javascript linked to it, but to spam the link 8 times a second with a decreasing number of id ultimately did not work. The browser would just crash.

Then I realized I can make a little script and run it on the site.

```
var id = 995544;
function loop() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    id--;
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/api/v1/cancel_buy_order',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            api_key: $('#apiKey').text(),
            buy_order_id: id
        },
      });
    loop();
  }, 1000);
}
loop();
```

While this works, it would take me 11.5 days to remove all listings. Partially because the delay is 1 second as opposed to 1000/8. (The api only allows 8 request a second.) But the biggest reason would be because it attempts to remove listings that don't even exist.

What I mean by this is, Each by listing has a random increment after the last one (e.g. 994488 -> 994502 -> 994503 and so on).

I needed a way to find the buy order id, and then use it in the second code I put here.

```
 var id = (function () {
  var id = null;
   $.ajax({
     'async': false,
     'global': false,
     'url': '/api/v1/get_active_buy_orders',
     type: 'get',
     data: {
         api_key: 'myapikey',
         code: 'mycode',
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data){
         id = data
     }
   });
   return id;
   console.log(id);
  })();
```

This thankfully works, but unfortunately it does not parse the

```
"data" : {
"orders" : [
```

parts of the JSON.

While I would love not to ask how to parse the JSON on here and find the answer for myself, I'm either googling the wrong thing, or am too dumb to understand how to do it.

So my question is, how would I parse JSON in JQuery?

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "orders" : [
      {
        "buy_order_id" : 503154,
        "market_hash_name" : "P2000 | Pulse (Field-Tested)",
        "price" : "0.03",
        "suggested_price" : "0.14",
        "state" : "LISTED",
        "created_at" : 1454390518,
        "updated_at" : 1454390518,
        "settled_with_item" : null
       },
      ],
      "page" : 88
    }
}
```

Comment: you want all `buy_order_id`s from JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all buy_order_ids from JSON try the following snippet

```js
x = {
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "orders": [{
      "buy_order_id": 503154,
      "market_hash_name": "P2000 | Pulse (Field-Tested)",
      "price": "0.03",
      "suggested_price": "0.14",
      "state": "LISTED",
      "created_at": 1454390518,
      "updated_at": 1454390518,
      "settled_with_item": null
    }, {
      "buy_order_id": 502154,
      "market_hash_name": "P2000 | Pulse (Field-Tested)",
      "price": "0.03",
      "suggested_price": "0.14",
      "state": "LISTED",
      "created_at": 1454390518,
      "updated_at": 1454390518,
      "settled_with_item": null
    }, ],
    "page": 88
  }
}
var ids = x.data.orders.map(function(d) {
  return d.buy_order_id
})
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ids, 0, 4) + '</pre>')
```